# MySQL group by where day <= x

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I need some help figuring out the correct SQL statement.

If've got a table with the following structure:
id, product_id, units, timestamp

I wan't a list which contains the all over units per day. A product has maximum one record per day. 
So my first try was:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(timestamp) as day, SUM(units) as overall_units 
FROM 
    tbl 
GROUP BY 
    DATE(timestamp);
```

Normally this should do it. But sometimes there are days where is no record for a product. Nevertheless the units are still in the warehouse so they should be in the calculation.

For example:

We have 3 products. Cars, pens and wheels.
Records from 2012-10-20:

Cars => 5
Pens => 20
Wheels => 4

Records from 2012-10-21
Cars => 5
Wheels => 6

My query would give the following results:

2012-10-20 => 29

2012-10-21 => 11

But I want, that if there's no record for a product for the day it should use the record for this product which is the nearest one back in time.

So it should be:

2012-10-21 => 31

I hope you understand my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    dd.ddate AS day
  , SUM(t.units) as overall_units 
FROM
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
              product_id
          FROM 
              tbl
        ) AS dp
    CROSS JOIN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
              DATE(timestamp) AS ddate
          FROM 
              tbl
        ) AS dd
    JOIN 
        tbl AS t
            ON t.id =
                ( SELECT
                      tt.id
                  FROM
                      tbl AS tt
                  WHERE 
                      tt.product_id = dp.product_id
                    AND
                      tt.timestamp < dd.ddate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                  ORDER BY tt.timestamp DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                ) 
GROUP BY 
    dd.ddate ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   MAX (DATE(timestamp) ) as day, SUM(units) as overall_units 
FROM tbl
```

update ::

```
 SELECT max(day),sum(ou) from  
     (  select DATE(timestamp) as day, SUM(units) as ou 
        FROM tbl 
        GROUP BY   DATE(timestamp);
      )
```

inner qry will return

```
2012-10-20 , 29
2012-10-21 , 11
```

and the final query will return

```
 2012-10-21 , 40
```

Comment: But this doesn't seem to work with `GROUP BY 
    DATE(timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the `DISTINCT()` function. 
The query could be something like: `SELECT DISTINCT(product_id), * FROM tbl ORDER BY timestamp DESC;` The use PHP to loop through your results and cumulate the units.